# Sending automatic SMS alerts Python/Django

Tags: python, django, sms, sms-gateway

I'm building a website using Django. And I want that users can be able to receive alerts via SMS when new topics are posted.

I tested textlocal but I had an issue when trying to send SMS to multiple numbers (`numbers = ['xxxxx','xxxxx']`) .(I don't want to use `group_id`).

Generally I want to be able to do something like this:

```
numbers = (SELECT number FROM users WHERE SMS_subscribe=1)
sender = 'mywebsite'
message = 'Hey, a new topic was posted'
send_sms(numbers, message, sender)
```

---

My textlocal test code:

```
#!/user/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from urllib import urlencode

def send_sms(uname, hash_code, numbers, message, sender):
    data = urlencode({
            'username' : uname,
            'hash' : hash_code,
            'numbers' : numbers,
            'message' : message,
            'sender' : sender,
            'test' : True
        })


    #data = data.encode('utf-8')
    request = Request('https://api.txtlocal.com/send/?')
    response = urlopen(request, data)
    return response.read()


def just_one_sms_message(message, annonce_link, sender):
    links_len=len(annonce_link) + len(sender) + 1
    sms_max_len = 160 - links_len
    if len(message)>sms_max_len:
        message = message[:sms_max_len-6]+'... : '
    else:
        message += ' : '
    return message + annonce_link + '\n' + sender


username = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com' 
hash_code = '3b5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8d83818'
numbers = ('2126xxxxx096','2126xxxxx888')
annonce_link = 'http://example.com/'
sender = 'sender'
message = 'New topics..'
message = just_one_sms_message(message, annonce_link, sender)

resp = send_sms(username, hash_code, numbers, message, sender)
print resp
```

Executing this code I get this error :

```
{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"errors":[{"code":4,"message":"No recipients specified"}],"status":"failure"}
```

But if I change: `numbers=('2126xxxxx096')`it works.

---

What is the best way or web service to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues you're running into. The first is how `tuple` literals are defined.

`('somenumber')` is equivalent to `'somenumber'` in python. It's just a string. The parentheses alone do not define a `tuple` literal. To define a single-element `tuple` literal, you need a trailing comma of the first element. E.G. `('somenumber',)`.

The second issue is how `urlencode` works. For each value in the data dictionary, it asks for the string representation.

In the case of `('2126xxxxx096','2126xxxxx888')`, since it's evaluated as a `tuple`, it's encoded as `('2126xxxxx096','2126xxxxx888')`, resulting in `%28%272126xxxxx096%27%2C+%272126xxxxx888%27%29`.

In the case of `('2126xxxxx096')`, since it's evaluated as a `string`, it's encoded as `2126xxxxx096`. Notice the lack of junk characters like `%28` and `%29`.

So, in short, since the value of `numbers` in the `urlencode` dictionary is a `tuple` when you have multiple numbers, you need to convert the `tuple` into a comma-separated `string`. This can be accomplished via `",".join(numbers)`, which in the case of `('2126xxxxx096','2126xxxxx888')` produces `2126xxxxx096%2C2126xxxxx888`. With the fixed encoding, your message should now send to multiple numbers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm beginner in Python/Django. Thanks a lot I learned many things from your answer. And it solved my issue.

Comment: Glad to be of help! As a piece of advice, I'd highly recommend using `pdb` to watch what's happening. `pdb`, the python debugger, lets you inspect variables and function calls wherever/whenever. To have the debugger invoked, just insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` wherever you'd like to start debugging.